# Sql query to select row count even when at least one value matches in column out of list of variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sugarcrm

I have a table name called Kits in which has 5 columns for Book ISBN.

- So i want to select Row even when at least 1  value of ISBN gets matched with any of the 5 columns(ISBN_BOOK1,ISBN_BOOK2,ISBN_BOOK3,ISBN_BOOK4,ISBN_BOOK5) of table kits meant for Storing ISBN.
- if any one of the ISBN exists then return count.

I have written an sql query for this but I am getting row output only if  last value is matching with any row. In my case the value is 7589765432 Here is my sql query:

```
Select * 
  from kits k
  left 
  join kits_cstm kc
    on k.id = kc.id_c 
 where '8192933563' 
   and '8192933567' 
   and '8192933568' 
   and '8192933564' 
   and '7589765432' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c,kc.isbn_book_2_c,kc.isbn_book_3_c,kc.isbn_book_4_c,kc.isbn_book_5_c) 
   and kc.city_c = 'BAN' 
   and kc.kit_for_c = 'SCHL' 
   and k.deleted = 0 
 ORDER 
    BY k.kit_id DESC
```

Comment: hard to understand.  but your structure is certainly not correct - all those AND conditions do not have a proper looking structure.

Comment: Where to begin... Well, start with normalisation

Comment: numbers like 8192933563,.. etc are ISBN numbers and i want to select records in which even any single value of isbn already exists , in the column in any order.all the 5 value can also be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "AND" to conjoin values to one operator

WRONG WAY: WHERE '8192933536' AND '8192933567' IN ({array])
RIGHT WAY: WHERE '8192933536' IN ({array]) AND '8192933567' IN ({array])

But I suspect that what you're actually trying to do is more like:

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM 
     kits k LEFT JOIN kits_cstm kc
          ON k.id = kc.id_c 
WHERE 
     ('8192933563' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c,kc.isbn_book_2_c,kc.isbn_book_3_c,kc.isbn_book_4_c,kc.isbn_book_5_c)
      OR 
     '8192933567' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c,kc.isbn_book_2_c,kc.isbn_book_3_c,kc.isbn_book_4_c,kc.isbn_book_5_c)
      OR 
     '8192933568' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c,kc.isbn_book_2_c,kc.isbn_book_3_c,kc.isbn_book_4_c,kc.isbn_book_5_c)
      OR 
     '8192933564' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c,kc.isbn_book_2_c,kc.isbn_book_3_c,kc.isbn_book_4_c,kc.isbn_book_5_c)
      OR 
     '7589765432' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c,kc.isbn_book_2_c,kc.isbn_book_3_c,kc.isbn_book_4_c,kc.isbn_book_5_c) 
      )
AND
     kc.city_c = 'BAN' 
AND
     kc.kit_for_c = 'SCHL' 
AND
     k.deleted = 0 
ORDER BY 
     k.kit_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is NEVER going to work: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

```
'a' AND 'b' AND 'c' IN (....)
```

is going to be executed as

```
('a' AND 'b') AND ('c' IN (...))
    TRUE      AND (....)
```

You cannot just make up your own parsing rules for SQL.

You also should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables. What if you need 6 isbn's at some point. Now you have alter your table. The ISBNs should be in their own child table, reducing your problem to a simple `where subtable.isbn IN ('a', 'b', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your tables.  But, if you are stuck with this data structure, then just use multiple `in` statements.  Also, you don't want a `left join`, you want a regular `join`:

```
Select count(*) 
from kits k join
     kits_cstm kc
     on k.id = kc.id_c 
 where '8192933563' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c, kc.isbn_book_2_c, kc.isbn_book_3_c, kc.isbn_book_4_c, kc.isbn_book_5_c) 
   and '8192933567' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c, kc.isbn_book_2_c, kc.isbn_book_3_c, kc.isbn_book_4_c, kc.isbn_book_5_c) 
   and '8192933568' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c, kc.isbn_book_2_c, kc.isbn_book_3_c, kc.isbn_book_4_c, kc.isbn_book_5_c) 
   and '8192933564' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c, kc.isbn_book_2_c, kc.isbn_book_3_c, kc.isbn_book_4_c, kc.isbn_book_5_c) 
   and '7589765432' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c, kc.isbn_book_2_c, kc.isbn_book_3_c, kc.isbn_book_4_c, kc.isbn_book_5_c) 
   and kc.city_c = 'BAN' 
   and kc.kit_for_c = 'SCHL' 
   and k.deleted = 0 
ORDER  BY k.kit_id DESC
```